# Dropdown menu with html and css, want it to stay visible until clicking elsewhere

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

I'm trying to make dropdown menus which look something like MacOS menu bar menus (see the code snippet here). They're looking and working ok so far, but the menus really should stay visible until the user clicks (or taps) somewhere on the screen. As it is currently, they become "hidden" again as soon as you move out of the menu.

So far it's being done with pure HTML and CSS, but my intuition tells me this will need a sprinkling of JavaScript to achieve the effect I'm after -- but my JavaScript is still a bit lacking.

I think each `ul` element needs an `onhover` event which sets its visibility to `"visible"`, then the root window or document needs an onclick event to set everything below the first level of #menu items to `"hidden"`. Does anyone care to have a go at this?

```css
#menu {z-index: 9;
       font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}


#menu >  ul{
    
    padding: 0px 10px;
    margin: 0;
}


#menu ul {

    list-style: none;    
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 3px; 
    padding-right: 3px;
    width: auto;
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
    margin-left: 0px; 
}

#menu ul ul li {
    width: 150px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}



#menu a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}


#menu >  ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0.95;
    font-size: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.24); 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#menu > ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: -3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;

}

#menu > ul  ul > li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

#menu > ul  ul > li:first-child {
    margin-top: 3px;
}


#menu ul ul hr
{
    border: 1px solid rgb(201, 201, 201); 
    margin: 0px -15px;
    width: 165px;
}


#menu .li-selected
{
    color: #407af2;
}



#menu li > ul {
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}


#menu > ul ul ul li, ul ul  ul li a {
    background: rgb(240, 240, 240) !important;
}


#menu.hoverable li:hover
{
    background: rgb(0, 144, 248);
}


#menu.hoverable ul li:hover > a
{
    color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}


/* 
#menu.hoverable ul li:hover > ul, #menu.hoverable ul li > ul.visible,
#menu.hoverable ul li > ul > li > ul.visible
{
    visibility: visible;
}
*/ 


#menu.hoverable ul li > ul.visible,
#menu.hoverable ul li:hover > ul,
ul.visible
{
    visibility: visible;
}



#menu.hoverable ul ul  ul li:hover, #menu.hoverable ul ul ul li:hover a {
    background: rgb(0, 144, 248) !important;
}

.li-heading, #menu.hoverable .li-heading:hover {
    background: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
    padding: 5px 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-weight: bohttp://localhost:9000/sessions/102df527a94/index.html#ld;
}


.menu-right-icon
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    transform: scale(1.8,1.0);
}


.nav-caret
{
    transform: scaleX(1.8);
}


html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #aaa;
    font-family: "helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto minmax(15px, auto) 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "menu" "tree" "inspector" "viewport";
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
    .grid {
        /* grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, min-content)  minmax(auto, min-content)  minmax(auto, 100%); */
        /* grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, min-content) minmax(10px, 20px) minmax(auto, 100%); */
 /* grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, min-content) minmax(auto, 100%);  */
 grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 20%)  minmax(auto, 100%);  
        grid-template-rows: auto minmax(auto, min-content) minmax(auto, 100%);
        grid-template-areas:     "menu menu "
         "tree viewport"
                              "inspector viewport";
    }
}

.menu {
    grid-area: menu;
    background: rgb(219, 230, 250);
    z-index: 9;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.menu-image {
    width: 16px;
    height: 15px;
}

.tree {
    grid-area: tree;
    background: rgb(209, 209, 209);
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

#tree-root {
    padding: 0 15px
}

.inspector {
    grid-area: inspector;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
/*    resize: horizontal; */
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 5;
}

.viewport {
    grid-area: viewport;
    background: #e8e8e8;
    /* resize: both; */ 
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

.viewport div:first-child {
    text-align: center;
}

.growlr-tree ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 1em;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.growlr-tree li {
    white-space: nowrap;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}




.expanded,
.directory,
.leaf {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.expanded {
    color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.directory {
    color: rgb(212, 113, 113);
}

.leaf {
    color: rgb(100, 190, 104);
}

.inspector .heading {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(82, 82, 82);
}


.inspector-table, .inspector-table tr, .inspector-table tr td
{ 
    overflow: auto;
    cellpadding: 0;
    cellspacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
}

.inspector-table td
{
    border: 1px solid rgb(168, 168, 168);
    padding: 3px 2px;
    text-align: left;
}


.inspector-table td:first-child
{
   color: rgb(78, 78, 78);
   text-align: center;
}

.inspector-table tr:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: rgb(233, 242, 255);
}



.i-t-m
{
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;
}

.i-t-v
{
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;

}

.i-t-v-click
{
    color: blue;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: monospace;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: pre;
}

.i-t-v-unclick
{
    color: black;
    font-family: monospace;
    width: 10px;
    white-space: pre;
}



#svg-1 path {vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke};


#x3dom-1 {background: #d3d3d3;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang="en"><head><title>Genworks GDL - assembly</title><meta charset="UTF-8" /><link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/gwl/images/favicon.ico" /><div id="KDpzdGFuZGFyZC1qYXZhc2NyaXB0LXNlY3Rpb24p">
<link id="fontawesome-css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous" /></div></head><body>
<div class="grid">
  <div id="menu-cell" class="cell menu"><div id="KDptZW51KQ"><script>

 function hideMenus(event)
{
  var related = event.relatedTarget;
  var  isInMenu = ((related) && (document.querySelector('#menu').contains(related)));
  if (!(isInMenu))
  {
  setTimeout(removeMenuHoverable, 50);
  setTimeout(removeMenuVisible, 50);
  }
}

 function hideTopMenus (event)
{
  var obj = event.target;
  var uls = document.querySelectorAll('#menu > ul > li > ul');
  for (var i = 0; i < uls.length; i++)
      uls[i].classList.remove('visible');
}

 function removeMenuHoverable()
  {
    document.querySelector('#menu').classList.remove('hoverable');
   }

 function removeMenuVisible ()
 {
   var uls = document.querySelectorAll('#menu ul ul');
   for (var i=0; i< uls.length; i++) 
     uls[i].classList.remove('visible');
 }

 function addVisible(event, level)
 {
   var obj = event.target;

   if (obj.tagName == 'A')
    obj = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
 

   if (obj.tagName == 'UL')
   {
      obj.classList.add('visible');
      var par = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
      if (par.tagName == 'UL')
      { par.classList.add('visible');
      }
      event.stopPropagation();

   }
}


</script>
<nav id="menu">
<ul onmouseover="
  hideTopMenus(event);

">
<li>
  <a href="#" tabindex="0" onfocus="

document.querySelector('#menu').classList.add('hoverable');

" onblur="hideMenus(event);"><img class="menu-image" src="https://genworks.com/static/gwl/images/logo.png" alt="G" />
  </a>
<ul onmouseover="
 addVisible(event, 1);

"><li><a href="#" class="li-selected"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Development</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" tabindex="0" onfocus="

document.querySelector('#menu').classList.add('hoverable');

" onblur="hideMenus(event);">File
  </a>
<ul onmouseover="
 addVisible(event, 1);

">
<li>
  <a href="#">New
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Open
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Save
  </a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" tabindex="0" onfocus="

document.querySelector('#menu').classList.add('hoverable');

" onblur="hideMenus(event);">Edit
  </a>
<ul onmouseover="
 addVisible(event, 1);

">
<li>
  <a href="#">Color
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Line Thickness
  </a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" tabindex="0" onfocus="

document.querySelector('#menu').classList.add('hoverable');

" onblur="hideMenus(event);">Tree
  </a>
<ul onmouseover="
 addVisible(event, 1);

"><li><a href="#"> Add Node...</a></li><li><a href="#"> Draw Node...</a></li><li><a href="#"> Add Leaves...</a></li><li><a href="#"> Draw Leaves...</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" tabindex="0" onfocus="

document.querySelector('#menu').classList.add('hoverable');

" onblur="hideMenus(event);">View
  </a>
<ul onmouseover="
 addVisible(event, 1);

">
<li>
  <a href="#" tabindex="0">Camera Point
<span class="menu-right-icon">
  <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>
</span>
  </a>
<ul onmouseover="
 addVisible(event, 2);

"><li><a href="#" class="li-selected"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Trimetric</a></li><li><a href="#"> Top</a></li><li><a href="#"> Front</a></li><li><a href="#"> Left</a></li><li><a href="#"> Bottom</a></li><li><a href="#"> Rear</a></li><li><a href="#"> Right</a></li>
</ul>
</li><li></li><li><a href="#"> Fit to View</a></li><li><a href="#"> Clear!</a></li><li></li>
<li>
  <a href="#" tabindex="0">Graphics Format
<span class="menu-right-icon">
  <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>
</span>
  </a>
<ul onmouseover="
 addVisible(event, 2);

"><li><a href="#"> SVG</a></li><li><a href="#" class="li-selected"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Raphael</a></li><li><a href="#"> x3dom</a></li><li><a href="#"> png</a></li><li><a href="#"> jpeg</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" tabindex="0" onfocus="

document.querySelector('#menu').classList.add('hoverable');

" onblur="hideMenus(event);">Develop
  </a>
<ul onmouseover="
 addVisible(event, 1);

"><li><a href="#"> Update!</a></li><li><a href="#"> Set Self!</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav></div>
  </div>
</div></body></html>
```

Comment: I've updated the CSS to simplify the selectors, and added :focus to one of them. It almost works, but the issue is the menus don't disappear when you hover over other menus (so I guess I could say it works "too well" now lol). On a touch interface I think it would be perfect. But we still need something to hide the open menus when hovering over other menus, when an old one is still in focus (I know it seems I want my cake and eat it too -- but it's the way the Mac menus work. I'm sure they have active code behind those, though, not just something like declarative CSS)...

Comment: Added a bit of messy Javascript and now it's getting closer to what I want. Still a few details to clean up, like if you leave the submenus in a certain way, the parent still disappears... Also made it so you have to click the menu bar in the first place, to make it "hoverable."

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using javascript (in this example using jQuery):

1. Replace your css `#menu li:hover>ul`

By creating a class named "visible":

```
#menu li>ul.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.95;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

2. Use JQuery
3. Add `.hover()` to detect mouse over your menu and `addClass()` "visible" to the current dropdown menu (ul)
4. Add `.click()` which will remove class "visible" from any dropdown menu

Full working code at: https://jsfiddle.net/ha1omd2w/

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but the working code is flashing, and the submenus don't show up.

Comment: You are welcome @djc I rechecked the link above and it’s working correctly. Maybe you opened JSFiddle on a smartphone?

Comment: @djc The code was corrected, you are right, it flashes when you hove the submenu, and this was corrected by changing $( "#menu li" ) to: $( "#menu > ul > li" )

Comment: Hmm, still flashing for me (on Chrome/Mac), and submenus still not displaying. I'm also trying to get by w/o JQuery.  I ended up adding a bit more (messy) JS, you can see the updated snippet above. Still needs work (the menu bar items lose their highlighting when you leave a menu, and if you leave a submenu in a certain way the parent disappears), but I daresay it's working smoothly for what it does so far...

Comment: Maybe the code was not forked correctly on JSFiddle try now: https://jsfiddle.net/7ysjrcL6/ (tested on Chome / Mac too)

Comment: Yep, the flashing is fixed now. Submenus still don't show up. But I like the apparent simplicity of your approach compared with what I have now. You're being more surgical with query selectors, and you're avoiding the old-fashioned :onclick, :onhover etc on HTML elements which I am still using. I might try to retro-fit your approach into what I end up with. I think the JQuery you're using is just kind of shorthand, looks like the same things can be done with vanilla JS...

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have to change your markup slightly, but using the `:focus` pseudo class will probably do what you want. If you extend all of your `:hover` styles with `:focus` you will see that when you click a menu item it will stay selected. The issue though is you are clicking and giving the `<a>` tag focus that is inside of the `<li>` tag. That means you won't be able to use child selectors the same way.

You could do one of two things to solve this:
1) Remove the wrapping `<li>` tag and update your styles accordingly.
2) Add `pointer-events: none` to the `<a>` tag which would effectively pass the click event to the `<li>` and put focus there which you could then target with styles. This also means though that if you have a `href` on the `<a>` tag you will technically not be able to click to navigate to it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on :focus. I've updated the CSS to simplify the selectors, and added :focus to one of them. It almost works, but the issue is the menus don't disappear when you hover over other menus. On a touch interface I think it would be perfect. But we still need something to hide the open menus when hovering over other menus, when an old one is still in focus (I know it seems I want my cake and eat it too -- but it's the way the Mac menus work. I'm sure they have active code behind those, though, not just something like declarative CSS)...

Comment: Ah, sorry... I did not catch that part. Technically that means you will not be able to achieve this with CSS alone even with sibling selectors.

I'd recommend doing this with an `.active` class and javascript instead. Adding all of jQuery to your stack JUST for handling hover/click events and adding classes would be overkill.

Start by putting all of your active styles into the .active class that you can add onto the single menu item. That way you can trigger the menu item by adding an active class to a single DOM element.

Comment: Then you have a single class that controls your expected functionality which is easier to control with your logic in JS. A good resource to help you perform some of the abstracted things jQuery will for you is this: youmightnotneedjquery.com

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedbacks. I've incorporated some of them into the version below, which I feel is starting to look reasonable. Anyone who's interested, please poke around with it and see where it's still lacking. I know it will break on older browsers [1], and I know I should be assigning the events with JavaScript rather than mixing them in the HTML with various on... tag attributes (will fix later).  But anyone who's interested please feel free to tell me where the logic or styling falls apart or where it's working harder than it needs to be...

[1] Although I plan to punt on doing any real work to support older browsers with this, maybe I could use one of these "polyfills" I hear people speaking of... or at least display a "Not Supported" message for non-modern browsers...

```js
function makeMenuBarHoverable (event)
{
 document.querySelector('#menu').classList.add('hoverable');
}


function hideMenus(event)
{ 
  var lis;
  var obj = (event && event.target);
  var menu = document.querySelector('#menu');
  
  if (obj && menu.contains(obj))
  {
    while (obj && (!(obj.tagName == 'LI'))) obj = obj.parentNode;
    var ul = obj.parentNode;
    lis = ul.querySelectorAll('li');
  }
  else
  {
    lis = menu.querySelectorAll('ul li');   
    menu.classList.remove('hoverable');
  }

  for (var i=0;i<lis.length;i++)
   {
    var li = lis[i];
    if /* ((! (li == obj)) && (li.classList.contains('visible'))) */ 
       (! (li == obj))
       li.classList.remove('visible');
   }
}

setTimeout(hideMenus, 10);

document.addEventListener('click', hideMenus);

function addVisible(event, level)
{
  var obj = event.target;

  while (obj && (obj.tagName != 'UL')) obj = obj.parentNode;
  if (obj.tagName == 'UL') obj = obj.parentNode;
  if ((obj.tagName == 'LI') && (! (obj.classList.contains('visible'))))
    obj.classList.add('visible');
}
```

```css
#menu, #menu ul, #menu li, #menu a
{
    z-index: 9;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}


#menu >  ul
{
    padding: 0px 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu ul
{
    list-style: none;    
}

#menu > ul > li
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 3px; 
    padding-right: 3px;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0px; 
}

#menu ul ul li
{
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#menu ul ul li a
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}

#menu  ul li
{
    outline: none;
}

#menu a
{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}


#menu >  ul ul
{
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0.95;
    font-size: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.24); 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#menu > ul ul ul
{
    left: 100%;
    top: -3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

#menu > ul  ul > li:last-child
{
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

#menu > ul  ul > li:first-child
{
    margin-top: 3px;
}


#menu ul ul hr
{
    border: 1px solid rgb(201, 201, 201); 
    margin: 0px -15px;
}

#menu li > ul
{
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

#menu > ul ul li
{
    position: relative;
}

#menu > ul > li, #menu > ul > li > a
{
    background:  rgb(219, 230, 250); !important;
}


#menu ul li ul li > a,
#menu ul li ul li
{
    background: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}

#menu  ul li.visible > a,
#menu  ul li.visible, 
#menu.hoverable  ul li:hover > a,
#menu.hoverable  ul li:hover
{
    color: rgb(240, 240, 240)  !important;
    background: rgb(0, 144, 248)  !important;
}

#menu ul li ul .li-selected
{
    color: #407af2;
}


#menu.hoverable ul li.visible > ul,
#menu.hoverable ul li:hover > ul
{
    visibility: visible;
}

.li-heading, #menu.hoverable .li-heading:hover
{
    background: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
    padding: 5px 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.fa-check
{
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.menu-right-icon
{
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 12px;
    transform: scale(1.8,1.0);
}


html {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}

.grid {
 display: grid;
 grid-gap: 1px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #aaa;
 font-family: "helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr;
 grid-template-rows: auto minmax(15px, auto) 1fr 1fr;
 grid-template-areas: "menu" "tree" "inspector" "viewport";
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
 .grid {
     /* grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, min-content)  minmax(auto, min-content)  minmax(auto, 100%); */
     /* grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, min-content) minmax(10px, 20px) minmax(auto, 100%); */
 /* grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, min-content) minmax(auto, 100%);  */
 grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 20%)  minmax(auto, 100%);  
     grid-template-rows: auto minmax(auto, min-content) minmax(auto, 100%);
     grid-template-areas:     "menu menu "
                  "tree viewport"
                              "inspector viewport";
 }
}

.menu {
 grid-area: menu;
 background: rgb(219, 230, 250);
 z-index: 9;
 font-size: 15px;
}

.menu-image {
 width: 16px;
 height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang="en"><head><title>Genworks GDL - assembly</title><meta charset="UTF-8" /><link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/gwl/images/favicon.ico" /><div id="KDpzdGFuZGFyZC1qYXZhc2NyaXB0LXNlY3Rpb24p">
<link id="fontawesome-css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous" /></div></head><body>
<div class="grid">
  <div id="menu-cell" class="cell menu"><div id="KDptZW51KQ">
<nav id="menu">
<ul id="menu">
<li id="(the :logo)" tabindex="0" onmouseover="hideMenus(event);" onclick="makeMenuBarHoverable(event);">
  <a href="#" id="a (the :logo)"><img class="menu-image" src="https://genworks.com/static/gwl/images/logo.png" alt="G" />
  </a>
<ul id="(the :logo)" onmouseover="addVisible(event, 1);"><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#" class="li-selected"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Development</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="(the :file)" tabindex="0" onmouseover="hideMenus(event);" onclick="makeMenuBarHoverable(event);">
  <a href="#" id="a (the :file)">File
  </a>
<ul id="(the :file)" onmouseover="addVisible(event, 1);">
<li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);">
  <a href="#">New
  </a>
</li>
<li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);">
  <a href="#">Open
  </a>
</li>
<li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);">
  <a href="#">Save
  </a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="(the :edit)" tabindex="0" onmouseover="hideMenus(event);" onclick="makeMenuBarHoverable(event);">
  <a href="#" id="a (the :edit)">Edit
  </a>
<ul id="(the :edit)" onmouseover="addVisible(event, 1);">
<li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);">
  <a href="#">Color
  </a>
</li>
<li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);">
  <a href="#">Line Thickness
  </a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="(the :tree)" tabindex="0" onmouseover="hideMenus(event);" onclick="makeMenuBarHoverable(event);">
  <a href="#" id="a (the :tree)">Tree
  </a>
<ul id="(the :tree)" onmouseover="addVisible(event, 1);"><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> Add Node...</a></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#" class="li-selected"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Draw Node...</a></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> Add Leaves...</a></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> Draw Leaves...</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="(the :view)" tabindex="0" onmouseover="hideMenus(event);" onclick="makeMenuBarHoverable(event);">
  <a href="#" id="a (the :view)">View
  </a>
<ul id="(the :view)" onmouseover="addVisible(event, 1);">
<li id="(the :view :camera-point-menu)" tabindex="0" onmouseover="hideMenus(event);">
  <a href="#" id="a (the :view :camera-point-menu)">Camera Point to view from this direction
<span class="menu-right-icon">
  <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>
</span>
  </a>
<ul id="(the :view :camera-point-menu)" onmouseover="addVisible(event, 2);"><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#" class="li-selected"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Trimetric</a></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> Top</a></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> Front</a></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> Left</a></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> Bottom</a></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> Rear</a></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> Right</a></li>
</ul>
</li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><hr /></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> Fit to View</a></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> Clear!</a></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><hr /></li>
<li id="(the :view :graphics-format-menu)" tabindex="0" onmouseover="hideMenus(event);">
  <a href="#" id="a (the :view :graphics-format-menu)">Graphics Format 
<span class="menu-right-icon">
  <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>
</span>
  </a>
<ul id="(the :view :graphics-format-menu)" onmouseover="addVisible(event, 2);"><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#" class="li-selected"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> SVG</a></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> x3dom</a></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> png</a></li>
<li id="(the :view :graphics-format-menu :tree-menu)" tabindex="0" onmouseover="hideMenus(event);">
  <a href="#" id="a (the :view :graphics-format-menu :tree-menu)">Tree
<span class="menu-right-icon">
  <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>
</span>
  </a>
<ul id="(the :view :graphics-format-menu :tree-menu)" onmouseover="addVisible(event, 3);"><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> Add Node...</a></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#" class="li-selected"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Draw Node...</a></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> Add Leaves...</a></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> Draw Leaves...</a></li>
</ul>
</li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> jpeg</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="(the :develop)" tabindex="0" onmouseover="hideMenus(event);" onclick="makeMenuBarHoverable(event);">
  <a href="#" id="a (the :develop)">Develop
  </a>
<ul id="(the :develop)" onmouseover="addVisible(event, 1);"><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> Update!</a></li><li onmouseover="hideMenus(event);"><a href="#"> Set Self!</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav></div>
  </div>  
  </div>
</div></body></html>
```